# What is the meaning of the middle of late?

Tags: meaning

This is the context:

> By the middle of late ’70s, ...

When is this middle of '70s ?

Edit:
The full sentence is

> By the middle of late ’70s, the computing industry had tried all the concepts we’ve described, and it was still unhappy.

The source is THINKING FORTH by Leo Brodie, p. 30 (ISBN 0-9764587-0-5)

Comment: It could simply be a typo for 'middle or late '70s'.

Comment: This isn't context. This is just the quote. Please give more context and the source of the quote.  I think an article is missing. "the middle of the late 70s" makes more sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When we talk about any 's, we mean the decade of that year. So, 80s means 80 to 89 and so on. In short, it's the decade we refer.

When you say late 70s, it's the last few years of the decade means maybe 76 to 79. Even middle of it is confusing. Maybe 77 or 78 **but** it sounds down to me. To me, it's poorly used words.

Late 70s is pretty popular to tell and so is mid 70s where the former may mean 77, 78, or 79 and the latter may mean 74/5/6 approximately. We use 's to denote a period more than a year, just not to be precise. So, it's difficult to come up with *a particular number.*

Answer (score 2):

It is rather imprecise..

The "late 70s" are the later years in the 1970s, roughly 1977-1979, so the middle would be in 1978.

The "late 70s" may be associated with certain styles, like disco or punk, so saying "the middle of the late 70s" may be more evocative than saying 1978.